Slicing in custom Keras loss function
I'm trying to replicate TIM-Loss in Keras. The loss function requires splitting the model predictions into query and support sets. My implementation looks like this:
def new_mutual_information_loss(
    support_labels: list[int],
    hyper_alpha: float = 0.1,
    hyper_lambda: float = 0.1
):
    """Mutual information loss for TIM.

    References:
    - https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2020/file/196f5641aa9dc87067da4ff90fd81e7b-Paper.pdf
    """
    num_supports = tf.constant(len(support_labels))

    def __loss(y_true: tf.Tensor, y_pred: tf.Tensor):
        # Split the support and query predictions
        support_preds = y_pred[:num_supports]
        query_preds = y_pred[num_supports:]

        # Split the support and query labels
        support_true = y_true[:num_supports]

        # Posterior distribution distribution over labels given features
        # Equation (1)
        # Softmax not needed since MLP predictions are already softmaxed,
        # but it doesn't seem to hurt either
        p_ik = tf.nn.softmax(query_preds, axis=1)

        # Marginal distribution over query labels
        # Equation (1)
        p_hat_k = tf.reduce_mean(p_ik, axis=0)

        # Label-marginal entropy H(Y_Q)
        # Equation (2)
        H_Y = -tf.reduce_sum(p_hat_k * tf.math.log(p_hat_k))

        # Conditional entropy of labels given the query raw features H(Y_Q|X_Q)
        # Equation (2)
        H_Y_given_X = tf.reduce_sum(p_ik * tf.math.log(p_ik), axis=1)
        mean_H_Y_given_X = tf.reduce_mean(H_Y_given_X)

        # Mutual Information
        # Equation (2)
        mutual_info = H_Y + mean_H_Y_given_X * hyper_alpha

        # Cross-Entropy Loss for the support set
        # Equation (3)
        cross_entropy_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            categorical_crossentropy(
                support_true,
                support_preds
            )
        )

        # Total Loss
        # Equation (3)
        total_loss = hyper_lambda * cross_entropy_loss - mutual_info
        return total_loss

    return __loss

For transductive inference, the model inputs are constructed as follows:
    # Append query encodings to supports
    combined_encodings = np.concatenate(
        [support_encodings, query_encodings],
        axis=0
    )

    # Pad out query labels for inference
    if query_labels is None:
        query_labels = np.zeros((query_encodings.shape[0], num_classes))
    combined_labels = np.concatenate(
        [support_labels, query_labels]
    )

    # Set batch size to include all samples (supports & queries)
    num_supports = len(support_encodings)
    num_queries = len(query_encodings)
    batch_size = num_supports + num_queries

    # Fit model (transduction)
    model.fit(
        combined_encodings, combined_labels,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=verbose
    )

The model is a simple Keras FNN with BatchNormalization and Dropout.
If I provide the actual labels from the test data for query_labels instead of padding with zeros, the model seems to reach a significantly higher accuracy. However, the slice pertaining to the query labels is not used inside the loss function.
Is there a possibility (maybe due to graph execution?) the slicing in the loss function is not respected when training the model?
What I tried:

Defining the slice index as a tf.constant did not have any effects.
Neither did re-assigning y_true to the slice instead of assigning to a new variable.
Printing the shapes of the slices using tf.print("Support labels", tf.shape(support_true)) shows the expected slice shapes, as if the slicing operation was respected.
Removing BatchNormalization and Dropout from the model did not affect the issue.


the model seems to reach a significantly higher accuracy. How do you compute the accuracy?

@Lescurel By calling model.predict() on the query samples (after fit) and evaluating against the query labels using sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.

If I implement the loss function by calling model.fit() with the support data only and calculate the query predictions inside the loss funtion using model(query_encodings) the slicing issue is avoided entirely.
The model now converges ~10x slower but reaches the same accuracy as when including the actual query labels in the initial approach.
